# Remote debugging using gdbserver over ssh fails with Remote connection closed

Tags: c++, ssh, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug a c++ app, which runs on a remote host, via a linux VM.

My VM is an Ubuntu 16.04 and the remote host has a yocto built linux OS.

The only option of communication between is target and host is via ssh.

So I tried to use ssh tunnel to achieve remote debugging giving the following commands:

```
$ gdbserver :5555 ./myApp  (in remote host)

$ ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.x -L 5555:localhost:5555  (in VM)

$ gdb target remote localhost:5555  (in VM)
```

However every time I get the following error :

```
channel 3: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed Remote connection closed.
```

Does anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open

Comment: try setting selinux to permissive